# How to connect my vcl client to my vcl server remotely using datasnap from delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, vcl, datasnap, noip

I am using Windows 11 Pro.

I am on a local network, and I am using a No-IP address and connected to No-IP address.

I opened port 7777 on my Windows firewall and my router.

I have created a server DataSnap application (Windows VCL) and a client DataSnap application (Windows VCL).

Server components:

`DSServer1`
`DSServerClass1` connected to `DSServer1`
`DSTCPServerTransport1` connected to `DSServer1`
`DSTCPServerTransport1` Port = 7777

Client components:

`SQLConnection1`
`Driver` = DataSnap
`ConnectionName` = DataSnapCONNECTION
`Params`
[ DriverName = DataSnap , HostName = ?????.ddns.net , Port = 7777 , ConnectionName = DataSnapCONNECTION ]

When running the server and trying to connect `SQLConnection1` from the client side, if I connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or my local network IP `192.168.1.7`, it connects successfully.

But, if I try to connect to my No-IP host, I get a error

> Socket Error # 10060
> Connection timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem
The problem was
I was trying to connect to the server through the same network
So I tried to connect from another computer connected to another internet network and it worked fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It could also be improved by using punctuation.